# Matrix associated with difference equations

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations

I am reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.02754) article which talks about iterative matrices associated with difference equations.

> [image]

According to how the authors have defined the highlighted entries does not match up as left hand side entry gives a $0$ though the corresponding entry on the right hand side is $1$. Can someone please explain this discrepancy ? If there's any related reference to read do let me know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: (2.5.) has an obvious typo: the degree three recurrence should be $d_n = ad_{n-1}+bd_{n-2}+cd_{n-\mathbf 3}$. Besides that, the given initial conditions are inconsistent with this recurrence.

Comment: @amd, thank you. Now I see. Would you be able to tell me valid initial conditions that is consistent with the corrected version of yours. Appreciate it.

Comment: See the general $k$-degree recurrence that follows to see what it should be.

Comment: @amd, isn't the $k$-degree recurrence is just $d_k = a d_{k-1} + b d_{k-2} + c d_{k-3}$ ?

Comment: No. The right-hand side has $k$ terms (hence the name). However, that is what the degree 3 recurrence should’ve looked like.